# JavaFX empty tableview with numbers

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a tableview that has columns of types (SimpleStringProperty, SimpleIntegerProperty)

```
STRING1   STRING2       INTEGER1          INTEGER2
#######   #######       ########          ########

a            b             9                 10
a            c             9                 12
b            d             0                  0
```

Now, in the 3rd row, the 3rd and 4th column have values as 0. The type of which is SimpleIntegerProperty.

I would like it if the 0s don't show up in the table and the cell appears empty.
Can you please advice on how i may do this?

P.S: I am using property listeners for making an editable table.
Strings are initialized to null and hence the table is blank but integers are getting initialized to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to extend from ListCell and override the updateItem method.
In that method you have to check if the SimpleIntegerProperty equals 0 and probably call setText("") then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a TableCellFactory which returns your customized TableCell-Object. In the TableCell's updateItem()-method you can call setText() as suggested by Lukas Leitinger.

```
 TableColumn columnInteger2 = new TableColumn("Integer2");
        columnInteger2.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<MyVo,String>("fieldInteger2"));

        columnInteger2.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn tableColumn) {
                return new TableCell<String, Integer>(){
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Integer integer, boolean b) {
                        if (integer != null) {
                            super.setText(integer == 0?"":integer.toString());
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```